# Парсинг JSON из локального файла

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, json, iphone

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть локальный JSON файл в проекте и мне надо из него достать данные. но почему-то, когда я пытаюсь вывести эти данные в консоль у меня пишет "(null)" в консоли, вместо отображения данных  Выручите пожалуйста!

JSON

```
{"cities":[
    {"cityName":"Minsk", "countryCode":"BY", "cityDescription":"Minsk is the capital of Belarus"},
    {"cityName":"Moscow", "countryCode":"RUS", "cityDescription":"Moscow is the capital of Russia"},
    {"cityName":"Prague", "countryCode":"CZ", "cityDescription":"Prague is the capital of Czech Republic"},
    {"cityName":"Washington", "countryCode":"USA", "cityDescription":"Washington is the capital of United States of America"},
    {"cityName":"Stockholm", "countryCode":"SWN", "cityDescription":"Stockholm is the capital of Sweden"},
    {"cityName":"Beijing", "countryCode":"СHN", "cityDescription":"Beijing is the capital of China"},
    {"cityName":"Tokyo", "countryCode":"JPN", "cityDescription":"Tokyo is the capital of Japan"},
    {"cityName":"London", "countryCode":"UK", "cityDescription":"London is the capital of Great Britain"},
    {"cityName":"Madrid", "countryCode":"SPN", "cityDescription":"Madrid is the capital of Spain"},
    {"cityName":"Paris", "countryCode":"FR", "cityDescription":"Paris is the capital of France"}    
]}
```

Objective-C

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"citiesJSON" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *cityNames = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"cityName"];
NSLog(@"%@", cityNames);
```

http://www.cyberforum.ru/objective-c/thread1570741.html#post8288750

Comment: а чего код не скопировали сюда?

Answer (score 2):

Имя ключа в dictionary 'cities' а не 'cityName'. Измените последнюю строку:

```
NSArray *cityNames = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"cities"];
```